all traffic goes through the WIREGUARD VPN tunnel
I have installed wireguard several times and on several different operating systems (windows, linux, etc), and whenever I configure my client to pass all its traffic through the wireguard vpn, the connection becomes very slow, too slow .
Policy on the client: AllowedIPs “0.0.0.0/0
I have tried modifying the mtu on the client to a value where the packets are not broken but the connection is still very slow. The quality of network servers without VPN is very high, and they are not saturated in terms of resources. Does anyone understand what could be happening?
CONFIG WIREGUARD:

# Server
[Interface]
PrivateKey = PRIVATEKEY
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PreUp =
PostUp =  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT;
PreDown =
PostDown =  iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -D INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT;

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUBLICKEY
PresharedKey = PRESHAREDKEY
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32

----------------------------------------

# Cliente
[Interface]
PrivateKey = PRIVATEKEY
Address = 10.8.0.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUBLICKEY
PresharedKey = PRESHAREDKEY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
PersistentKeepalive = 0
Endpoint = IPSERVWIREGUARD:51820


okay, I edited it
